# @RenderSection Equivalent in Blazor?

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-client-side

Razor pages have a mechanism where you can reference named sections in your layout, and then specify them in your pages that use that layout. For example, if your Layout (_Layout.cshtml) looks like this:

```
@using...
...
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<body>
...
@RenderSection("modals", required: false)
...
```

and then in your dashboard page, for example, you'd have:

```
<div>
...
</div>
...
...
@section modals
{
    <div class="modal-container>...</div>
    <div class="modal-container>...</div>
}
```

that would inject the contents of `@section modals...` into the place in the layout where `@RenderSection("modals")` is.

How can this be done in Blazor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, no such feature is currently supported in Blazor. Blazor team and the community have been discussing the necessity of this feature over a year now, but for no avail. [Read here about Sections in Blazor.](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10452)

However, if you're looking for a 'temporary solution', you may read a comment by [SteveAndeson](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/857#issuecomment-427833621)  about how to pass parameter values from a Blazor component page to its layout. I know that you're looking for a way to render the @Body plus @EndBody, but the principal remain the same: You have to create a layout component instead of the default layout

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 11):

Section support will be added with .NET 8 ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-3/?cid=vs_developer_news#sections-support-in-blazor)):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Sections
...
<div class="top-row px-4">
    <SectionOutlet SectionName="TopRowSection" />    
</div>
```

```
<SectionContent SectionName="TopRowSection">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
</SectionContent>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a component to get something similar to sections:

https://github.com/inspgadget/BlazorSections